# How to deal with tabs as views?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity, android-tabs

I've created tabs as views. But I didn't find any info on how to manipulate theses views. For example if I want to display a listview in one and a form (tablelayout) in another. Can I have separate layouts for each tab? And more importantly where do I include java code regarding each tab?

Here's my java code:

```
public class TabWorkEntryActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.tabworkentry);

TabHost  mTabHost = getTabHost();


  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("top10").setIndicator("Top 10").setContent(R.id.Top_10));
  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("billable").setIndicator("Billable").setContent(R.id.Billable));
  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("product").setIndicator("Product").setContent(R.id.Product));
       mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("regular").setIndicator("Regular").setContent(R.id.General));

  mTabHost.setCurrentTab(3);


}
```

Any kinda help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways of putting content and dealing with tabs:
1. you create an activity, and put the activity in the tabHost
2. you deal with the content, in the same code you add tabs (blow all the setup stuff)
I always use the 2nd way because my codes are organized, so it's not so big...

Here is a sample layout, with the content as another layout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/checkall_tab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <include
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        layout="@layout/checkall" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/view_tab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <include
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        layout="@layout/viewall" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/run_program"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <include
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        layout="@layout/programs" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Okay. Now if I'm using the second approach can I use separate layouts for my tabs or do I have to include everything in a single layout like my activity?

Comment: yourTabSpec.setContent(R.id.the_id_of_your_tab);

Comment: the "layout" to put in the tabView must be specified in the layout of the tab host... check it out how i did it

Answer (score 0):

I made this code using Android 4.0 tabView. try understanding it...
You gotta instantiate the TabHost, then create tabs with this object.
And then add the tab to TabHost.
To findViews by id, you don't need to pass the "view" on the tab that you are accessing.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    checkAll = tabHost.newTabSpec("checkAll");
    viewAll = tabHost.newTabSpec("viewAll");
    runProgram = tabHost.newTabSpec("runProgram");

    viewAll.setContent(R.id.view_tab);
    viewAll.setIndicator("View All");
    tabHost.addTab(viewAll);

    checkAll.setContent(R.id.checkall_tab);
    checkAll.setIndicator("Check All");
    tabHost.addTab(checkAll);

    runProgram.setContent(R.id.run_program);
    runProgram.setIndicator("Run program");
    tabHost.addTab(runProgram);
}
```

Comment: I've done the same thing. Haven't I? My question is now suppose I want 'view_tab' as my listview then where do I write my java code related to that tab?